# Mongodb multiple $lookup depends on the first lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi i have a mongo scheme called "payments" that has a 2 keys that optional:
userId or representativeId **(if userId exist representativeId not exist and same about representativeId)**.
When i found the payments scheme based on cheque scheme that using the $match to filter the result based on my data, I bring all payments in the first lookup that match for my query , in the second and third lookup I want to bring the user data / representative data.
Maybe it will be mix of them its ok, its what I want to see if one of them does not exist the other must to be exist.

I want to get the final array that include the user or the representative or mix of them in the same array.

I am using aggregate to implement this.

the problem its give me back a empty array when 2 of the lookup show(user and representative),
but when I comment the lookup of the user or the representative, and i left with 2 lookup one for payment and after that last lookup user / representative and its work me like I want but just for user / representative just if i remove one of the lookup.
I want its bring my array with two of them.

```
const userAndRepData = await ChequeDB.aggregate<{[key: string]: any}>([
      {
          $match: {
              $and: [
                  {
                    'chequeNumber': {
                        $in: chequeData.map(c => c.chequeNumber)
                    },
                    'accountNumber': {
                        $in: chequeData.map(c => c.accountNumber)
                    }
                  }
              ]
            
          }
      },          
      {
          $lookup: { 
              from: 'payments',
              localField: 'paymentId',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'payment'
          }
      },
      {
          $unwind:'$payment'
      },
       {
          $lookup: {
              from: 'representatives',
              localField: 'payment.representativeId',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'representative'
          }
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$representative'
      },
      {
          $lookup: {
              from: 'users',
              localField: 'payment.userId',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'user'
          }
      },
      {
          $unwind: '$user'
      },
      {
        $project: {
            user: 1,
            _id: 0,
             representative: 1
        }
      }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use data from one `$lookup` in the next one since the data from `$lookup` still hasn't been loaded at the moment query is executing, i.e. `payment.representativeId` will be null.

You can write resource intensive queries that would work around this, but the easiest and best (performance-wise) way to execute this query would be to have `representativeId` and `userId` stored on the `Cheque` collection.

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: If possible, you would need to save `representativeId` and `userId` on your `Cheque` collection so you can use it in a lookup. Not sure how your code looks like, but you would need to update your Cheque insert/update methods to save these fields too.